# How to catch UnsatisifiedLinkError when using NDK-built library in an Android app?

Tags: android, linker, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have an Android project that contains a class that uses JNI to pull a value from a C function. The C function was built into a library using NDK. The value returned from the C function is in turn used to initialize a variable inside a class when its first loaded. This works fine. However, I also want it to work when the library is missing by providing a default value. So Im using something like this:

```
static native String getstring();

static {
        try {
                System.loadLibrary("library");
                NAME = getstring();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                NAME = "Default";
        }
}
```

Despite the catch, Im still getting a UnsatisfiedLinkError when I try to run this code with the library missing. Why am I not catching the exception? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`UnsatisfiedLinkError` is not a subclass of `Exception`. The hierarchy of `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is:

```
Throwable->Error->UnsatisfiedLinkError
```

You better catch `UnsatisfiedLinkError` if you want to handle it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Catching that specific error and setting a default value works perfectly. Thanks!